# Git push to remote repository started with git init

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a folder with VS Solution with few projects and so on. I've created a GitHub repository and uploaded the contents of that directory via the web interface.
Now, changes have been made to my projects, and I want to start pushing those to my github repository. So I use `git init`, than stage and commit files.

But I can't push because `"Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally."`

But I can't pull either because

`git pull RemoteName master` // refusing to merge unrelated histories

So I try to `fetch` and `merge` in order to use `--allow-unrelated-histories` with merge as suggested somewhere, but fail miserably because of not understanding how merge really works while cursing I didn't red git manual after chapter 1 :)

Seriously how to proceed from here?

`git fetch RemoteName` //Ok

`git merge RemoteName` //No remote for the current branch.
`git merge RemoteName master` //merge: RemoteName - not something we can merge

Comment: `git push -u master origin` for the initial push.

Comment: $ git push -u master origin
error: src refspec origin does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'master'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two unrelated projects. One on github and second on your hdd, because you copied files only via web browser without git commands. Try this - backup your project on hdd to another directory and then delete project from directory, which you want to synchronize with github. Then in your directory write command `git clone your_link_from_github`. The project downloads from github to your hdd and will be synchronized.

You can find nice cheat sheet about git commands [here](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html).