# How to add and pull remote git repo to the project which has lots of untracked files

Tags: git, synchronization, dropbox

I’d like to work on the project on the laptop and destop sharing git repo through the Dropbox. 
I have lots of utracked files which I don't want to put in git repo.
What is the right way to copy the project to another computer in that case?

I’ve been trying to use the widely used technique of putting the external repo on the Dropbox:

**On Desktop:**

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git init --bare ~/Dropbox/git/myProj
git remote add db ~/Dropbox/git/myProj
git push --set-upstream db master
```

**on Laptop:**

1) **Copy all the project files from the Desktop to the Laptop**,

2) continue with git:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add db ~/Dropbox/git/engme
git pull db master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

However, this produces an error:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>           ... Please move or remove them before you can merge. Aborting

Please help…

I understand I'm able to copy untracked files after `git pull` to the clean local repo. But that's not convenient and I think there's a much easier way...  The clonning isn't a way too because of extra files.

Comment: What is the overall workflow you're aiming for?  (To put it another way, why didn't you do the standard thing of doing a `git clone` to start the laptop repo?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push to remote repository started with git init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861850/git-push-to-remote-repository-started-with-git-init)

Comment: @Scott Weldon Definitely it is not a duplicate as it is question combining git repo and file syncing service and asking for solution for certain errors.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworthm , I think, cloning won't got because I have files which I'm not gonna track with git.

Comment: @pedrouan: Both questions have the same root cause: instead of doing `git clone` on the new computer, the OP copied the files over and did `git init` (etc.), and thus the "refusing to merge unrelated histories" error. The answer to that question would also be a valid answer here, thus the dup flag. (The only difference is using Dropbox as the remote instead of GitHub.)

Comment: @Scott Weldon , clonning won't go for me because I have other files outside the git repo.

Comment: @zhekaus What kind of other files? If you have files that are not tracked by Git, then **by definition** Git will not help you in moving those files to another computer. If you just have some large files that you don't want bloating your repo, maybe look into [Git LFS](//git-lfs.github.com/). Regardless, you never want to do `git init` twice for the same repo, even if on different machines.

Comment: I've retracted my duplicate flag. The double `git init` stuff is a red herring; this question is really about transferring untracked files to another computer. However, the question is currently unclear. OP: (1) please answer the question in my previous comment (and [edit] this information into your post), and (2) I recommend cutting the part showing what you have tried, because that's not going to help you transfer untracked files, and distracts from the core of your question.

Comment: The question's still unanswered. Somebody help, please!

Answer (score 0):

**It is not necessary to add remote origin** when using file syncing services like Dropbox. I am using Dropbox with git for years, and I just do these for an init:

```
$work:# cd /Users/Work/Dropbox/MyProject
$work:# git init
$work:# git add .
$work:# git commit -m 'message'
```

**That's it.**

So this I did on my first computer and checked that Dropbox fully synced my files. Then came to my laptop with Dropbox logged in with the same account. I opened Terminal:

```
$peter:# cd /Users/Peter/Dropbox/MyProject
$peter:# git status

On branch master. Nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Now you can make some changes. In the morning you come to your computer and when you type git status, you see what you would see at home. Not committed changes / untracked files etc - depending on what your were really doing.

It is like you are still on your work computer, as your repo with you is that one you have set at work - thanks to Dropbox.

As you are for example in the office at your machine, that has Dropbox app and it is syncing its folder and files, **it always plays like you are on your local computer**. Your repo is always synced locally as Dropbox is syncing it on background (unless you disallowed syncing or lost connection and files have not synced before you came home to your laptop).

So if you install Dropbox on another computer and install Dropbox app, you just make git status and you're 'home' :)

'Remote add' serves for adding remote repo, that is needed when you want e.g. to pull from external receiver and I don't think this Dropbox offers in any way. In your situation git looks confused, as it is like when you want to call yourself and your line is occupied.

Comment: A word of warning when syncing git with Dropbox. If you make changes in two computers before it has a chance to sync, Dropbox will create conflict resolution duplicates for a bunch the files in .git. It can be a mess to clean up.

Comment: @asmeurer Very useful note, thanks. Maybe I remember this situation, once in few years. For people with unstable connection it be really messy.

Comment: @pedrouan, So, you store whole the project in the Ddropbox, don't you. However, my project folder is quite big...

Comment: @pedrouan, I use git to track particular files only. I think it's not a good idea to put all the files into repo. Especially when I'm not gonna chage them.

Comment: @zhekaus Yes I understand and that's why you could use git ignore for unwanted files or provide init (to make repo) for the folder that contains your wished files only. You can modify this solution as you want. As smaller the repo is, the more lightweight it is and it is better for speed of syncing etc... But I personally don't mind even big sizes.

Comment: @pedrouan , Yes, I use .gitignore. And I can pull the files from the remote repo to the empty folder with a brand new local git repo. But I don’t want to copy other files one-by-one from the laptop after that. I simply want to copy whole the folder from the laptop and connect it to the remote repo. After that I’m gonna use git push/pull to sync whiles on both environments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121567/discussion-between-pedrouan-and-zhekaus).